# Array of objects not keeping set values between for each loops

Tags: c++-cli

I am doing an assignment for school and have been stuck for the last few days, with a problem that I'm sure I have created myself. were supposed to be making one of three different dice games I chose one called LCR. I have most of the logic for the program finished I'm just having a problem with the array of objects I'm creating when the game starts (user defined number). For some reason when I initialize all the objects in the array with a for each loop I can set and get all the different parts of the object but once the loop is exited all the object information is lost. I, unfortunately, have to use CLI in this program because of another requirement. any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Here is the code that is giving me the problem.

```
    System::Array^ players = System::Array::CreateInstance(Player::typeid, numberOfPlayers);
for each(Player^ p in players){
    p = gcnew Player;
    tempNameAsString = tempNameAsNumber.ToString();
    p->setName(tempNameAsString);
}
con.writeStringToConsole("rolling dice \n");

for each(Player^ p in players){
    p->setDice(rollAllDice(3, 6, 1));
    //con.writeStringToConsole("player : ");
    //con.writeStringToConsole(p->getName());
    con.writeStringToConsole("rolled : ");
    con.writeVectorToConsole(translateDice(p->getDice()), " , ");
    con.writeStringToConsole("\n");
}

for each(Player^ players in players){
    con.writeVectorToConsole((players)->getDice(), " ,");
    con.writeStringToConsole("\n");
}
```

If I dont comment out the line

```
//con.writeStringToConsole(p->getName());
```

I get the error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in IT 312 LCR Dice Game.exe

here is the output when I do comment out the line

```
     How many players are there?: 10

     creating players

    rolling dice
    rolled : * , * , * ,
    rolled : C , * , * ,
    rolled : * , C , R ,
    rolled : * , * , C ,
    rolled : C , * , * ,
    rolled : * , * , * ,
    rolled : L , L , * ,
    rolled : * , R , * ,
    rolled : * , * , L ,
    rolled : C , * , * ,
```

For some reason if I try to accsess the player objects again I only get the 
last objects rolled dice.

```
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
    3 ,6 ,4 ,
```

Please let me know if im doing something stupid.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are multiple problems in this code.  First get ahead by declaring the array correctly, use `array<Player>^ players = gcnew array<Player>(numberOfPlayers);`  Next tackle the for-each loop, the array elements are not yet initialized so are still all nullptr.  Assigning p does not also assign the array element.  Use `for (int ix = 0; ix < players.Length; ++ix) players[ix] = gcnew Player;`

Comment: And do keep in mind that it is very unlikely that you are supposed to complete your assignment with C++/CLI code.  Maybe you'll get an A for effort, but do talk to your teacher to avoid a failing grade.  High odds that he prefers you seeing using std::vector.

Comment: Thank you for your help you totally helped me out. And the reason I am having to use CLI is he wants us to use streamWriter to read the game rules from a file and write the results to it. Thank you again for your help